# Как сделать плавный поворот игрока в Runner на платформе, которая должна разворачивать игрока

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр

На платформе мой игрок должен поворачивать на 90 градусов, чтобы бежать в другую сторону, но как сделать так, чтобы при повороте учитывалась и позиция с которой игрок встретился с этой платформой, и сколько игроку осталось идти по этому развороту. Нужен корректный поворот, чтобы, например, если игрок поворачивал с краю, то он и остался на краю после поворота. Игрок при этом ещё двигается влево и вправо.

Движение реализовано так:

```
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float straightAmount = Time.fixedDeltaTime * moveSpeed * (float)GameProperties.SideMove;
        float swerveAmount = Time.fixedDeltaTime * swerveSpeed * playerInputSystem.MoveFactorX * (float)GameProperties.MoveDirection;

        rb.velocity = transform.right * swerveAmount;

        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + (transform.forward * straightAmount));
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как реализовано ваше движение?

Comment: @AlemkhanUtepkaliev добавила в описание вопроса